# How to change non-color-related CSS after the color module has been used?

Tags: theming, caching

I haven't used the color module in years, since I try to avoid it because I know it kind of freezes your CSS changes.

I have a client who has been using color module with a customized version of the [Scholarly](http://www.morethanthemes.com/?q=themes/scholarly) theme, but does not seem to have the color picker enabled for it.

I'm trying to make some CSS changes for them that have nothing to do with changing colors, but my changes are not reflected on the site. It's pulling in an old version of styles.css. I've cleared the CSS cache and made sure aggregation is turned off on development so I'm pretty sure the color module is the culprit.

How do I clear or regenerate Color module's version of my site CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resave the color settings in the theme; see [color_scheme_form_submit()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!color!color.module/function/color_scheme_form_submit/7).

I'll look into what can be done inside the AdvAgg module: https://www.drupal.org/node/2461039

Edit: I've added this into advagg now. It will regenerate the color css.